# How to write "ℰ"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

could anyone please tell me how I can write "ℰ" in latex in both text and math enviroment? I have already tried `$\mathscr{E}$` and `$\mathcal{E}$`, but none of those are satisfying.

What I want to have is

[image]

but not any of these

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "in both text and math enviroment"? If it is a mathematical symbol, typeset it in math mode, if not, typeset it in textmode!

Comment: It is not clear what does not satisfy you, the font? the code needed to render the symbol? the size? What?

Comment: If you use pdfLaTeX, load the package `mathrsfs` and type `$\mathscr{E}$` if in text mode and `\mathscr{E}` if already in math mode.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not being clear enough. What I want to do is write "ℰ" like the one in this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TTesG.png and not like any of these: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n78w8.jpg

Comment: you will need to find what font was used for that sample and obtain it.  if it was in a pdf file, take a look at [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/579).

Comment: @Ben : you should edit your first post, and why not provide a MWE (cf. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/34551))

Comment: @Clément New users can't add images and a symbol is not really a MWE type of thing.

Answer (score 15):

Here are 3 more script fonts for which there exists a LaTeX package (in math mode): `Dutchcal`(from the esstix 13 font), Boondox  (from the stix fonts) (two variants) and Adobe's Bickham. All exist in regular and boldface. The following code allows to test them, commenting and uncommenting the relevant lines:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        \usepackage{dutchcal}
        %\usepackage{boondox-cal}
        %\usepackage{boondox-calo}
        %\usepackage{bickham}

        \pagestyle{empty}

        \begin{document}%
        \textbf{Dutchcal: }
        %\textbf{boondox-cal}
        %\textbf{boondox-calo}
        %\textbf{bickham}
        $ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c}
            \verb+ \mathcal + & \verb+ \mathbcal + \\[6pt]
            \mathcal{E} & \mathbcal{E}
            \end{array} $

        \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my first time posting here, so sorry if I caused some trouble.

Comment: Did you see the crystal ball I had voted you?

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't bother, so long as the symbol is a script E. However, here's a way to get the symbol you like; in the second line I show the character resulting with `\mathscr` (package `mathrsfs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{calligra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->callig15}{}

\newcommand{\calE}{{\!\!\text{\usefont{U}{calligra}{m}{n}E}\,\,}}

\begin{document}
Here is a $\calE$ (script E)

Here is a $\mathscr{E}$ (script E)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my first time posting here, so sorry if I caused some trouble.

Answer (score 10):

And here two versions with free fonts with use of the `fontspec` and `unicode-math` package.

These are mathematical symbols, so you will have to suround them by `$ $` or alike. But with `fontspec` you may load any font you like as main font and use it for your text as well.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\setmathfont{xits-math}
$\mscrE\mbfscrE$ (XITS Math)\\
\setmathfont{asana-math}
$\mscrE\mbfscrE$ (Asana Math)
\end{document}
```

[image]